# Automated Windows 10 System Image Backup Solution

Tags: windows-10, backup, azure

Over the last 2 years, I have had 3 separate Windows updates brick my computer forcing me to fully reinstall the OS. I am searching for the most effective backup solution to do all of the following:

1. Backup and restore personal files.
2. Backup and restore system files.
3. Automate backup creation (daily, weekly, or monthly)
4. Optionally, store the backups in Azure or OneDrive.

I see that Windows 10 offers 2 backup solutions.

1. File History - Does not seem to backup system files.
2. Recovery drive - Cannot be automated.

Am I missing something? Does the solution I am looking for not exist OOB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any backup relying on the running Windows instance is suspect. It's safer to use a third-party tool to back up the system files, or better, the *entire disk*, since these tools often enable the user to make a bootable recovery disk to use when the main Windows instance is defunct.

A number of excellent free tools are available, such as [Macrium Reflect](http://download.cnet.com/Macrium-Reflect-Free/3000-2242_4-10845728.html), [Paragon Backup & Recovery](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/br-free/#) and other [Alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/macrium-reflect/?license=free). They have saved me a great deal of time after Windows has munged my PC's. You can set some of these to schedule automatic backups, complete with image verification.